# Как выйти из обработчика при клике мышкой?

Tags: jquery, javascript

Всем привет! Как выйти из обработчика при вызове события click? Мне нужно, чтобы элемент зафиксировался в данном положении и событие mouseleave больше не срабатывало.
    $('div').on({mouseenter:function(){
    $(this).css("margin-left","-10px");
    },click:function(){
    return false;
    },mouseleave:function(){
    $(this).css("margin-left",0);
    }
    },'img');

Answer (score 1):

http://jsfiddle.net/7eCdz/ — попробуйте так (если я правильно понял вашу задачу)

```
$('div').on('mouseenter mouseleave click', 'img:not(.fixed)', function (evt){
    var $el = $(this), type = evt.type;
    if( type == 'click' ){
        $el.addClass('fixed');
    } else {
        $el.css('margin-left', -10 * (type == 'mouseenter'));
    }
});
```

Comment: Спасибо. А что такое img:not(.fixed)? Вообще принцип действия поясните, пожалуйста.

Comment: Смысл, не реагировать на элементы с классом "fixed" (название может быть любым).

Answer (score 0):

Воспользуйтесь [разовым обработчиком событий](http://jquery.page2page.ru/index.php5/%D0%A3%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0_%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE_%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0_%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8B%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B9). [ОФициальный мануал](http://api.jquery.com/one/).

Comment: Тогда и остальные события будут срабатывать один раз(mouseenter,mouseleave). А мне нужно кликом мышки зафиксировать свойство margin-left: -10px.